# Fix broken Message-ID field in Exim ACL

Tags: exchange, exim

Strange enough, some of my mail domain external sender used to send us messages where Message-ID field set to `$Null` like this:

```
    ...
    Date: Tue, 1 Dec 2020 07:16:22 +0000
    Message-ID: $Null
    Subject: Test
    ...
```

(looks like this is due to Exchange + Outlook setup used in their company, but can't find more info).

This is a bit problem until recent times as Apple updated iOS mail client and recent Mail app in iOS messed up all messages list when try to analyze such a message.

The fix I try to implement is simple, I try to add this action to Exim's `acl_check_data`:

```
    warn
      condition               = ${if eq{$h_message-id:}{\$Null}}
      remove_header           = message-id : message_id : Message-ID : Message_ID
```

I tried many ways of referencing Message-ID header line but even that condition yields to `true` the "remove header" action won't remove the Message-ID header line.

So please advice, **how can I remove or (better) replace broken header line of Message-ID with some correct value?**

Comment: Hi, is there any update? Please check if the below info is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that i'm not familiar with Exim, however, I found a documentation about the message-id in Exim for your reference, please check if it's helpful to you: **[Message processing](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-message_processing.html)**(`The Message-ID: header line`)

Did you deploy an Exchange server for your accounts? If so, you could create a transport rule to modify the message-id in the message header according to the conditions:[image]